# Problem with validatons inside a FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and I am currently building a website in angular, Im facing a problem that I cant solve with the angular documentation Im not quite understanding what's going on behind the problem.

In few words, I have a formArray(updateAddress) which contains a formGroup and some formControl's inside and I'm having a hard time trying to make the validations for it.

Code HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
<div *ngFor="let add of updateAddress().controls; let addIndex=index">
    <div formArrayName="updateAddress">
      <div [formGroupName]="addIndex">
        <label>
          Rua:
          <input type="text" formControlName="address">
        </label>
        <div
          *ngIf="profileForm.get('add.address')?.invalid && (address.get('add.address')?.dirty || profileForm.get('add.address')?.touched)">
          <div *ngIf="profileForm.get('add.address')?.errors?.required">
            Tem de escrever a rua da sua loja.
          </div>
        </div>
<button (click)="removeAddress(addIndex)">Remover</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addAddress()">Adicionar Morada</button>
</form>
```

Code TS:

```
  profileForm: FormGroup;

  control: any;

  
  constructor(
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
             ) {

    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      file: [''],
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]),
      email: new FormControl('',  [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]),
      password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7),Validators.pattern('(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!#^~%*?&,.<>"\'\\;:\{\\\}\\\[\\\]\\\|\\\+\\\-\\\=\\\_\\\)\\\(\\\)\\\`\\\/\\\\\\]])[A-Za-z0-9\d$@].{7,}')]),
      password2: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      nif: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\\d{9}')]),
      birthDate: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/.](19|20)\\d\\d$") ]),
      phoneNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\\d{9}')]),
      updateAddress: new FormArray([], Validators.required)
    });
   }

  updateAddress(): FormArray {
        return this.profileForm.get("updateAddress") as FormArray
  }

  newAddress(): FormGroup {
      return this.formBuilder.group({
        address: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        address2: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        postalCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        area: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      })
  }

  addAddress() {
      this.updateAddress().push(this.newAddress());
  }
  
  removeAddress(addIndex:number) {
    this.updateAddress().removeAt(addIndex);
  }
```

I really cant solve the problem in this validation because the validation feels like it goes through but doesnt appear any error in the webpage also I dont know if Im approaching this the right way or not aswell.

[image comproving the validation is working because submit is disabled but not sending a error when it should send under the "Rua" input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS2oH.png)

If someone can guide me or help I'll gladly appreciate it!

**UPDATE**

[As I said I think the validation works on the background but the error text that should appear just doesnt appear because Im not getting the ngIf right(I think)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w0gX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some items to note

You can initiate your form like below using `FormBuilder`

```
    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      file: [''],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')]],
      email: ['',  [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$")]],
      password: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7),Validators.pattern('(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!#^~%*?&,.<>"\'\\;:\{\\\}\\\[\\\]\\\|\\\+\\\-\\\=\\\_\\\)\\\(\\\)\\\`\\\/\\\\\\]])[A-Za-z0-9\d$@].{7,}')]],
      password2: ['', Validators.required],
      nif: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\\d{9}')]],
      birthDate: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/.](19|20)\\d\\d$") ]],
      phoneNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\\d{9}')]],
      updateAddress: this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.required)
    });

    newAddress(): FormGroup {
      return this.formBuilder.group({
        address: ['', Validators.required],
        address2: ['', Validators.required],
        postalCode: ['', Validators.required],
        city: ['', Validators.required],
        area: ['', Validators.required]
      })
  }
```

You can alse change `updateAddress` to a getter

```
  get updateAddress(): FormArray {
    return this.profileForm.get("updateAddress") as FormArray
  }
```

### To the problem

I believe the problem is in how you are trying to retrieve the errors

Try to use `formGroup.get('control_name').errors` in your case, the validation is applied to the controls inside the formArray so we need to access this and get the errors, something like

```
add.get('address').errors?.required
```

Below is a sample html.

```html
  <ng-container formArrayName="updateAddress">
    <div *ngFor="let add of updateAddress.controls; let addIndex=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="addIndex">
        <label>
          Rua:
          <input type="text" formControlName="address">
        </label>

        <div *ngIf="add.get('address').invalid && (add.get('address').dirty || add.get('address').touched)">
          <div *ngIf="add.get('address').errors?.required">
            Tem de escrever a rua da sua loja.
          </div>
        </div>
        <button (click)="removeAddress(addIndex)">Remover</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addAddress()">Adicionar Morada</button>
  </ng-container>
```

You can have a look at [This stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tgejc7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

### Edit

To initializa value for the form you can use `setValue` or `patchValue`. Something like below

```
   this.updateAddress.at(0).setValue({
      address: "My Address",
      address2: "My Address 2",
      postalCode: "77777",
      city: "Helsinki",
      area: "Some street"
    });
```

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-txgjzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I tried your solution but seems to do the same as before, he validates/invalidates on the background but doesnt show text error up

Comment: @DavidMoreira I have managed to reproduce your issue and have attached a sample working demo

Comment: IT WORKED SIR OWEN REALLY THANK YOU, now Im trying to initialize the form with the input showing and the button bellow but Im not getting it to work.

Comment: @DavidMoreira check the updated solution and the stackblitz demo

Comment: thank you so much, If I could give u 500 upvotes I would, thank you so much really

Comment: hello sir I would like to ask you help once again if u could help me, Im trying to pass the same thing but this time in typescript on the component, and when its form control Im passing it like this, get address() { return JSON.stringify(this.storeForm.get('addresses.address')?.value )}
, but when I need the array like before I need the ngfor, do u know how do I get the ngfor into my component.ts so I can pass the let add before like you did but in the component?

Comment: I am a bit lost, why are you turning the array to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Validators.required` at `FormArray` level. It means the size of `FormArray` must be greater than zero.

Individual validators on `newAddress` `FormGroup` fields like `address', 'address2` with check each field.

To better see what is happending add this line inside the form array loop:

```
 <pre> {{ 'invalid: ' + add.invalid + ', dirty: ' + add.dirty + ', touched: ' + add.touched }} </pre>
```

also display the whole form array errors

```
{{ profileForm.controls['updateAddress'].errors | json }}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dauzxq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I understand how you show me the method to get to see whats happening but I really just cant solve it, been trying to work around it for 3 days now.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Basically I cant make the text that should say something like Street required if touched/dirty invalid, when I do what you say it shows me that its either true or false the invalidations but the text error that I made on ngIf's just dont appear for some reason.

Comment: Can you update the stackblitz with what you have now, so I can check

Comment: Im sorry @robert I didnt see your reply, some people here just helped me, thank you very much anyways sir!

Answer (score 0):

#### Single Form

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" #ngForm="ngForm">
   <div>
      <input formControlName="firstName">
      <div class="error" *ngIf="
                            ngForm.submitted &&
                            formGroup.controls['firstName'].invalid &&
                            formGroup.controls['firstName'].touched" > </div>
   </div>

   <div>
      <input formControlName="lastName">
   </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl('',[ Validators.minlength(3) ]), 
   lastName : new FormControl('', [ ])
})
```

#### OR use formControl

```
<input [formControl]="formControl"/>
```

```
const formControl = new FormControl('',[]);
```

#### OR dynamically add the FormControls to the FormGroup.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input formControlName="firstName"  *ngIf="firstNameActive"/>
    <input formControlName="lastName"  *ngIf="lastNameActive"/>
</form>
```

> We should provide the input field for each FormControl.

```
  firstNameActive = false; 
  lastNameActive = false; 

  formGroup = new FormGroup({});

  addFirstName(){ 
      // Adding the form Control.
     formGroup.addControl('firstName', new FormControl(''))
     firstNameActive = true; 
  }
 
  removeFirstName(){ 
     // Removing the form control
     this.formGroup.removeControl('firstName')
     firstNameActive = false; 
  }
```

#### Tip

> There are observable properties in the form control and form group. I highly recommend you to use them in order to monitor form's validation status and value status.

```
formGroup.statusChanges
formGroup.valueChanges

formControl.statusChanges
formControl.valueChanges
```

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview

#### Let's talk about the FormArray.

1. we should provide the html input element for each FormControl created in the FormGroup with either formControlName or formControl in template file.
2. each formControlName in a html form element should be unique, formControlName represent the corresponding FormControl.
3. In this case, we will be using the same fields so we need a different form in our template file for each dynamically added address form.

#### Template

```html
<button type="button" (click)="addNewAddressForm()">
  Add New Address Form
</button>

<hr />
<br />


<form *ngFor="let form of groups()" [formGroup]="toFormGroup(form)">
  <label>
    City
    <input formControlName="city" />
    <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls.city.invalid">City is invalid!</div>
  </label>
  <br />

  <label for="state">
    State
    <input formControlName="state" />
    <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls.state.invalid">
      State is invalid!
    </div>
  </label>
</form>

<button type="button" (click)="submitForm()">Submit Address Form</button>
<br />

<strong>All Forms Value: </strong>{{ forms.valueChanges | async | json }}
<br />
<strong>All Forms State: </strong>{{ forms.statusChanges | async | json }}
```

#### Component TS

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-example',
  templateUrl: './form-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-example.component.scss'],
})
export class FormExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  forms = new FormArray([], Validators.required);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.forms.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  toFormGroup(f: any) {
    return f as FormGroup;
  }

  groups() {
    return this.forms.controls as FormGroup[];
  }

  controlNames(fg: FormGroup) {
    return Object.keys(fg.controls);
  }

  addNewAddressForm() {
    this.forms.push(
      new FormGroup({
        city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        state: new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(5),
        ]),
      })
    );
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log('Submitting Form: ', this.forms.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said my problem is on a formArray, as formGroup I got my validations to work.

Comment: Just updated the post with an example using FormArray. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In **Angular 10** (I think that  neither in **Angular 9** -but yes in Angular 7 and Angular 8-), you can not use the variable "add" to access to the FormGroup

So, to access to a FormControl inside a FormGroup inside a FromArray you can concatenate the formArrayName, the index and the formControlName using "."

```
formName.get(formArrayName+"."+index+"."+formControlName)

//in your case:
profileForm.get('updateAddress.'+addIndex+'.address')
//e.g.
<div *ngIf="profileForm.get('updateAddress.'+addIndex+'.address').touched &&
     profileForm.get('updateAddress.'+addIndex+'.address').errors?.required">
        Tem de escrever a rua da sua loja.
</div>
```

Other way is, as you has a getter of the FormArray -really it's not a getter, your should convert to getter-

```
//in your case:
 updateAddress().at(addIndex).get('address')
//e.g.
<div *ngIf="updateAddress().at(addIndex).get('address').touched &&
     updateAddress().at(addIndex).get('address').errors?.required">
        Tem de escrever a rua da sua loja.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Let's combine the FormGroup with FormArray

#### Template File

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <label>
    firstName
    <input formControlName="firstName" />
    <div class="error" *ngIf="profileForm.controls['firstName'].invalid">
      Not Valid
    </div>
  </label>
  <br />

  <label>
    lastName
    <input formControlName="lastName" />
    <div class="error" *ngIf="profileForm.controls['lastName'].invalid">
      Not Valid
    </div>
  </label>
  <br />

  <form
    [formGroup]="addressFormGroup"
    *ngFor="let addressFormGroup of addressFormGroups()"
  >
    <label>
      City
      <input formControlName="city" />
      <!-- <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls.city.invalid"> -->
      <div class="error" *ngIf="addressFormGroup.controls['city'].invalid">
        Not Valid
      </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </label>
    <br />

    <label for="state">
      State
      <input formControlName="state" />
      <div class="error" *ngIf="addressFormGroup.controls['state'].invalid">
        Not Valid
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <button type="button" (click)="addNewAddressForm()">
    Add Another Address
  </button>
</form>

<button type="button" (click)="submitForm()">Submit Address Form</button>
<br />

<strong> Form Value: </strong>{{ profileForm.valueChanges | async | json }}
<br />
<strong> Form State: </strong>{{ profileForm.statusChanges | async | json }}
```

#### Component TS File

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-example',
  templateUrl: './form-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-example.component.scss'],
})
export class FormExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    address: new FormArray([this.newAddressForm()], [Validators.required]),
  });

  newAddressForm() {
    return new FormGroup({
      city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      state: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  toFormGroup(f: any) {
    return f as FormGroup;
  }

  addressFormInstance() {
    return this.profileForm.controls.address as FormArray;
  }

  addressFormGroups() {
    return this.addressFormInstance().controls as FormGroup[];
  }

  addNewAddressForm() {
    this.addressFormInstance().push(this.newAddressForm());
  }

  toErrorMessages(errors: any) {
    return Object.values(errors);
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log('Submitting Form: ', this.profileForm.value);
  }
}
```

#### CSS file

```css
form {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```